# Mysql select and multiply some value problem occurs

Tags: mysql, sql, select

When I try to select some value from table, and return the value * 10, but the return value precision increased.

```
SELECT (10 * MinimumSize) AS MaximumSize FROM Test
```

When I run this sql command, the minimumsize is 0.001 a float value, but the maximumsize returns 0.010000000474974513.

So, how can solve this.

Comment: `ROUND(10*MinimumSize, 3)`

Answer (score 2):

Try with round function:

```
SELECT round((10 * MinimumSize),3) AS MaximumSize FROM Test
```

Answer (score 0):

The ROUND() function returns a number rounded to a certain number of decimal places

```
ROUND(number, decimal_places)
```

so if you need 3 decimal_places then use 3

```
  SELECT round((10 * MinimumSize),3) AS MaximumSize FROM t
```